# Symbol for \gg or equal

Tags: math-mode, symbols, amssymb

I need to (well, want to) use a symbol that is to `\gg` what `\ge` is to `>`: ,,`\gg` or equal``, if you will.

The obvious, quick-and-dirty solution was the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{statmath}
\newcommand{\ggeq}{\mathrel{\underline{\gg}}}
\begin{document}
$\bfu \ggeq \bfx$
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

Yet I feel that the resulting symbol is visually unappealing. Does anyone -- especially people who know what makes typeset symbols look good in the first place -- have tweaks, or other suggestions?

Or does such a symbol perhaps already exist in some package? I tried [detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html), but to no avail, and didn't find anything in [the list](https://ctan.org/pkg/comprehensive) either.

**EDIT:** since there seems to be some misunderstanding about the semantics of this symbol, `\gg` does not mean ,,much greater than`` in the context in which the new symbol is needed.

**EDIT 2:** used `\mathrel` rather than `\mathbin`, which is indeed more sensible; thanks to @mickep for the tip.

Comment: You are asking for a symbol that looks nice. This is an aesthetic judgment. I find the symbol that you do not like rather nice.

Comment: @Denis thanks! Yes, it is a judgement call. Yet I think there is such a thing as objectively beautiful typography; otherwise we might all be happily using Word instead of TeX!

Comment: Difficult to find an already existing symbol indeed. The easiest way would be not to use `\gg` but `>^{*}`  (for instance). Then you could use  `\geq^{*}` .

Comment: Not answering your question, but `\mathrel` might be better than `\mathbin`. Also, I cannot find this symbol in the very long uncode list of symbols. And "much greater than or equal to" sounds a bit obscure. May I out of curiosity ask for what it will mean?

Comment: Is this even a meaningful concept?  At what point does $u \geq x$ become $u \gg x$?

Comment: This is indeed a weird concept.  If I understand correctly, it works like this: 5 vs 500 is OK: 500 is much more than 5.  Also, 5 vs 5 is okay, because 5 is exactly equal to 5.  But 5 vs 6 is not okay: 6 is greater than 5, but only a little bit.  So we do NOT have "5 ggeq 6".

Comment: I feel like $\gtrsim$ (`\gtrsim`) conveys pretty much the same meaning and is much more widely recognized.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an extremely simple solution that does not have exactly the same spacing as `\gg`, but it's close. As noted by @Denis, you can redefine `\gg` if identical spacing is desired.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{statmath}

\newcommand{\ggeq}{\geq\!\!\!\geq}
\renewcommand{\gg}{>\!\!\!>}

\begin{document}

$\bfu \ggeq \bfx_{\bfu \ggeq \bfx_{\bfu \ggeq \bfx}}$

$\bfu \gg \bfx_{\bfu \gg \bfx_{\bfu \gg \bfx}}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice and simple. But as I see it the spacing between the two `>`  signs is not the same with `\gg` and with your `\ggeq`.

Comment: To overcome the problem, I would also add `\renewcommand{\gg}{>\!\!\!>}`

Comment: Good point @Denis. I updated my solution.

Comment: Excellent --- simple and effective. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure what the meaning would be. Anyway, here's a way to use the minus sign for the lower line. The resulting symbol will have (about) the same vertical dimension as `\geq`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\ggeq}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\gglleq@\gg}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\lleq}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\gglleq@\ll}}

\newcommand{\gglleq@}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1#2$}\sbox\tw@{$#1\leq$}%
  \vcenter to \dimexpr\ht\tw@+\dp\tw@{%
    \offinterlineskip
    \hbox{$\m@th#1#2$}%
    \vss
    \vbox to \dimen@{
      \vss
      \hbox to \wd\z@{$\m@th\mspace{-0.5mu}#1{-}\hss{-}\mspace{-0.5mu}$}%
      \kern-1.5\fontdimen8 \gglleq@font{#1} 3
      \kern-\fontdimen22 \gglleq@font{#1} 2
    }
  }%
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand{\gglleq@font}[1]{%
  \ifx#1\displaystyle\textfont\else
  \ifx#1\textstyle\textfont\else
  \ifx#1\scriptstyle\scriptfont\else
  \scriptscriptfont\fi\fi\fi
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

$a\ggeq b\geq c$ $\scriptstyle a\ggeq b\geq c$

$a\gg b$ $\scriptstyle a\gg b$

$a\ggeq b$ $\scriptstyle a\ggeq b$

$a\lleq b$

$a\ll b$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, very cool! I'll just nod and pretend I have any clue about how what's actually going on there. ,)